# Implement a property file as table

Tags: mysql, properties

I have a file .properties in my java project. Each time when I run the project, this
file get updated. I would like to implement this file in MySQL database through java code.

The structure of .properties file is as given

> Tue Jul 24 16:08:40 IST 2012
>
> LogMode=0
> Theme=Nimbus
> ReadCommunity=public
> WriteCommunity=private
> sysLoc=
> sysDesc=
> Port=161
> LogPath=
> TrapCommunity=public
> sysCont=

Any one please suggest a better way..

Comment: implement as in you want to update a row in a table?

Comment: not only the row, the entire table gets updated. now this file gets automatically created and updated in user documents folder

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get your question.

Comment: This existing properties file opens in notepad and i wanna change the entire file to Mysql as a table.  Hope u get it now

Comment: To read the property file in java, please take a look at example 2 here, http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ and you can set the property values in an insert/update query. Hope the property names remain constant (and i assume they are the column names). Hope this helps.